# Do we know $A$ if we know $z^T A z$ for all $z$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

Let $A$ be a matrix and suppose that

$$z^T Az$$

is known for all $z \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Is $A$ uniquely determined by all these values?

I needed this in the case that $A$ is symmetric, which I managed to prove. But I'm wondering about the general case. I suspect this to be false. Maybe a $2\times 2$-counterexample already exists.

Comment: You know the symmetric part of $A$. The skew-symmetric part is "not observable".

Comment: Could you present a concrete counterexample then?

Comment: Try $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks! It works as $z^ T A z = 0$ for all $z$, so we can just pick $A$ and a multiple of it.

Comment: The next natural question would be: does there exist a counterexample where we have $z^T A z = z^T B z$ for all $z$ and such that $A$ is not a multiple of $B$.

Comment: Consider the case where $A - B$ is skew-symmetric and, hence, "not observable".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider what happens if you transpose:

\begin{equation*}
    z^T A z = z^T A^T z
\end{equation*}